# Identify all possible combinations of a variable, including if values are missing in R

Tags: r, permutation, missing-data

I'm curious about the total number of ways people could have completed a training in a 'choose your own adventure format'

For example, there are 10 different levels to the training in total (i.e., level 1, 2 ... 10). People can complete 1:10; 10:1; 1,2,3,5,10; 2,1,3,5,4,6,7,9,8,10; or any combination of the levels using all, some, or none of the levels before taking their exit test.

**I'm hoping to find a way to make these combinations into a categorical variable because I'm wondering if sequence matters in the users likelihood of passing the exit test.**

I'd like to know how to do this in R, but if anyone has other creative solutions to offer regarding better ways to use sequence as a variable, I'm all ears for that too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at expand.grid

```
dat <- expand.grid(1:10, 1:10)

library(tidyr)

unite(dat, perms = Var1, Var2, sep=".")
```

Answer (score 2):

Because 1,2,3 is different than 3,2,1, you want to use permutations, not combinations.

In addition, the size of the target vectors should range from 1 to 10 (1,2 is a possible solution, never including 3).

Be careful, all permutations of 1:10 can take a while. Going much above 10 can increase the time and memory demands. Here is how to do it with 3 values.

```
library(gtools)
library(data.table)

levelnum <- 3
lval <- lapply(1:levelnum, function(x) {
  dat <- data.table(permutations(levelnum, x))
  setnames(dat, as.character(1:x))})
dval <- rbindlist(lval, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

Results in:

```
    1  2  3
 1: 1 NA NA
 2: 2 NA NA
 3: 3 NA NA
 4: 1  2 NA
 5: 1  3 NA
 6: 2  1 NA
 7: 2  3 NA
 8: 3  1 NA
 9: 3  2 NA
10: 1  2  3
11: 1  3  2
12: 2  1  3
13: 2  3  1
14: 3  1  2
15: 3  2  1
```

Changing `levelnum` to 10 results in 9864100 rows.

```
          1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
      1:  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
      2:  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
      3:  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
      4:  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
      5:  5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
     ---                              
9864096: 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  1  3  2
9864097: 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  2  1  3
9864098: 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  2  3  1
9864099: 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  1  2
9864100: 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

This took a few minutes to run.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `combn` inside `Map` and `unlist` afterwards to get a list of all combinations.

```
res <- Map(combn, 10, 1:10, simplify = FALSE)
unlist(res, recursive = FALSE)
```